# sketchup ruby api reset settings

Tags: api

Good afternoon!I'm new to programming , I started learning the sketchup ruby api, and after a few days of experiments, some functions stopped working in the program(I can definitely call dynamic components )Who knows what I've done and how to fix it?(Reinstalling sketchup didn't help)Version : SketchUp Pro 2017 17.0.18899 (x64).I apologize for my English, I do not know it well . Thank you to everyone who will help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-activate Dynamic component from the extension panel?
[image]

Comment: It turns out that when I right-click on a component, I can't open its parameters or create a dynamic component

Comment: if you are on before sketchup 2021.1, go to the windows menu/extension menu, and check dynamic component. if you are on after sketchup 2021.1, go to the windows extension/extension menu, and check dynamic component